# C Linker unable to find a GSL file. Linux

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker, gsl

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgsl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgslcblas
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [examples/slim_learn] Error 1
make[1]: *** [examples/CMakeFiles/slim_learn.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I am getting a linker error while I use the make command and I think this is because the linker isn't able to find a particular GSL file even after I have set the path for LIBRARY_PATH env variable which apparently the C linker consults if unable to find a file. I am stumped as to how to fix this error. I have also set the C_INCLUDE_PATH to my gsl directory on an unrelated (most probably) note. Any help in resolving this error would be much appreciated as I am very new to linux and have no idea how to proceed.

Setting LIBRARY_PATH :

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/home/PATH_TO_gls/gsl-1.16/
```

The make file is really long hence I am hesitant to post it here but this is the relevant part of the makefile: (please let me know if you would still like me to post the entire thing)

```
src/CMakeFiles/SLIM.dir/slim_fs_learn.c.o.requires:
.PHONY : src/CMakeFiles/SLIM.dir/slim_fs_learn.c.o.requires

src/CMakeFiles/SLIM.dir/slim_fs_learn.c.o.provides: src/CMakeFiles/SLIM.dir/slim_fs_learn.c.o.requires
        $(MAKE) -f src/CMakeFiles/SLIM.dir/build.make src/CMakeFiles/SLIM.dir/slim_fs_learn.c.o.provides.build
.PHONY : src/CMakeFiles/SLIM.dir/slim_fs_learn.c.o.provides

src/CMakeFiles/SLIM.dir/slim_fs_learn.c.o.provides.build: src/CMakeFiles/SLIM.dir/slim_fs_learn.c.o

src/CMakeFiles/SLIM.dir/slim_learn.c.o: src/CMakeFiles/SLIM.dir/flags.make
src/CMakeFiles/SLIM.dir/slim_learn.c.o: ../src/slim_learn.c
        $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_report "/home/nmuralid/Desktop/Nikhil Documents/Yelp_Research/SLIM Recommender/slim-1.0/b$
        @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --green "Building C object src/CMakeFiles/SLIM.dir/slim_learn.c.o"
        cd "/home/nmuralid/Desktop/Nikhil Documents/Yelp_Research/SLIM Recommender/slim-1.0/build/src" && /usr/bin/gcc  $(C_DEFINES)$
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you use `export`? can you post the exact command you are using?

Comment: I just used "make" command and this error occurred. Do you mean while setting the environment variables?

Comment: you should have export the vars. typing just make will result an error if you don't have a makefile in you path. if you have one - post it (or at least the relevant parts). any way, make should also print the command it executing. post this as well.

Comment: Does /home/PATH_TO_gls/gsl-1.16/ contain libgsl.so and libgslcblas.so?

Comment: /home/path_to_gls/gls-1.16/ contains a file called libgsl.la, and a hidden dir .libs/ in which I found the libgsl.so and libgsl.a files but still no sign of the libgslcblas.so

Comment: So should I set library path to have the path to the ./libs file so it can find the libgsl.so file?

Comment: No, you should have installed the library via 'libtool --mode=install' ... or simply 'make install'

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to set LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to the paths of the libgsl.so and libgslblas.so files. This was achieved as follows:

export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/home/path_to_gsl/gsl-1.16/cblas/./.libs/

export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/home/nmuralid/path_to_gsl/gsl-1.16/.libs/

We set the LIBRARY_PATH env in this case because the C-Linker looks inside these directories in-case it fails to find the files during linking.

gls-version 1.16 used.